# Resource was blocked due to MIME type mismatch

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have been getting this error of `The resource from “[URL and name of file]” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).` for *all* of my CSS and Javascript files.

The setup I currently have is a node.js server using Express and Express-Handlebars for routing and templates. I'm sure the issue is down to my routing of files which would have requests of dealing with routes like `/movies/:id` or `/search/query:`. I have kinda fixed the issue by creating two links to CSS and Javascript files in my `main.hbs` file (The one which is the default main template), one with a link from `/` and another for `/something/something`. Terrible practice I know. But up until now, it worked.

But this is why I am asking for help in solving the MIME type mismatch error once and for all. Because when I have uploaded it to my Digital Ocean server, it won't work at all. And I have no clue on how to fix it.

My file structure is as follows:

```
/
    views/
        css/
        js/
        layouts/
            main.hbs
    index.js
```

In index.js, I have the code to setup handlebars and some code managing CSS and Javascript files.

```
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    extname: '.hbs',
    layoutDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views/layouts')
}));

app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
```

An example of an route would be

```
app.get('/search/:query', (request, response) => {
    // Code goes here
});
```

I'm genuinely stuck on what to do. I feel like I have been to all corners of the internet and I cant find any solution to my issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

just try by removing . from above line of code use this                

**app.set('view engine', 'hbs')**

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

This has something to do with the dots. I had the same problem. I found out that all my files were in the form of filename.min.js . So I removed the first dot and changed the filename to filenamemin.js and it worked. Maybe express reads everything after the first dot as the file extension.